# camerax sample: Unresolved reference: WindowManager

Tags: android-camerax

I'm trying to compile the sample cameraxbasic but I get this error:
Unresolved reference: WindowManager
I checked gradle files and there is that dependency.

Comment: In particolar I get the error from CameraFragment.kt import androidx.window.WindowManager

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you solve it? Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

I reviewed the library change log at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/window and adjusted the sample with following these changes to make it work. Hope this helps!

1. use `implementation "androidx.window:window:1.1.0-alpha01"`
2. replace `WindowManager` with `WindowInfoTracker`
3. replace `WindowManager(context)` with `WindowInfoTracker.getOrCreate(view.context)`
4. replace `windowManager.getCurrentWindowMetrics().bounds` with `WindowMetricsCalculator.getOrCreate().computeCurrentWindowMetrics(requireActivity()).bounds`

Comment: Wow!  Thanks!  Would be nice if CameraXBasic team would update

Answer (score 0):

funny how Microsoft has a guide on `Window Manager` here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dual-screen/android/jetpack/window-manager/?tabs=views

guide says which packages to include and how to use in the code, specifically to answer the question:

```
windowInfoTracker = WindowInfoTracker.getOrCreate(this@MainActivity)
```

while android has no official guide and a broken use case at the official github CameraX sample https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic